# Bitcoin/Dogecoin Daemon RPC authentication - 401 status error

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, dogecoin

I'm trying to connect to a local dogecoin server with jsonRPC.

The dogecoin daemon is launched with the following parameters:

```
dogecoin-qt -server -testnet -gen -debug -debugnet -printtoconsole -rpcuser=user -rpcpassword=user
```

The following Java code is used to connect to the server:

I'm using com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.JsonRpcHttpClient

```
            JsonRpcHttpClient client = new JsonRpcHttpClient(new URL("http://user:user@localhost:22555"));

        String response = "";
        client.invoke("getinfo()", response);
        System.out.println(response);
```

It just won't accept any credentials at all, I've tried setting them on the conf file, command-line, etc.

```
Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://user:user@localhost:22555
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: So... does it work now or what?

Comment: The authentication part yes. (I cannot answer it myself within 8 hours). However you should take a look at this post http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7528/bitcoind-returning-invalid-json-rpc-2-0-response?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems that for some reason I didn't read this essential part:

> The easiest way to tell Java to use HTTP Basic authentication is to set a default Authenticator:

```
    final String rpcuser ="...";
  final String rpcpassword ="...";

  Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
      protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
          return new PasswordAuthentication (rpcuser, rpcpassword.toCharArray());
      }
  });
```